# Matching key/value pairs with comments

Tags: regex

For a JavaScript application, I'm trying to come up with a regex that will match key/value pairs in a string. It's working pretty well, but there is one last thing that I need to implement and I'm not sure how.

The syntax is very similar to what you'll find in a `.env` file. So key/value pairs look like `KEY=value`.

A few rules that I have already implemented:

- The key

  - alphanumeric string.
  - can't be empty and can't be a number.
  - may contain an underscore
- The value

  - can be string
  - may be surrounded by single or double quotes, or none at all.

Now I'm trying to add comments with `#` in there. It works, except when `#` is between the quotes. Any idea how to fix that? Thanks!

Here is my code sample:

```
// This is my regex
const regex = /^\s*(?![0-9_]*\s*=\s*([\W\w\s.]*)\s*$)[A-Z0-9_]+\s*=\s*(.*)?\s*(?<!#.*)/gi;


// Outputs [ "KEY=value " ] --> OK
const str = `KEY=value # Comment`;
console.log(str.match(regex));

// Outputs [ "KEY2=val" ] --> OK
const str2 = `KEY2=val#ue # Comment`;
console.log(str2.match(regex));

// Outputs [ "key3='value3' " ] --> OK
const str3 = `key3='value3' # Comment`;
console.log(str3.match(regex));

// Outputs [ "key_4='val" ] --> NOT OK
// Expecting [ "key_4='val#ue4' " ]
const str4 = `key_4='val#ue4' # Comment`;
console.log(str4.match(regex));
```

**EDIT:**

Here is another sample for testing:

```
# The following are matching
ONE = This is ONE
TWO=This is TWO
 THREE="This is 'THREE'"
 FOUR = "This is \"FOUR\""
fi_ve = 'This is \'FIVE\''
 six='This is "SIX"'
NUMBER7="This is SEVEN" # Comment for SEVEN
number8="This is EIGHT"#Comment for EIGHT
NINE="This is #9"
TEN=This is #10
ELEVEN=
TWELVE=10
THIRTEEN=TRUE
FOURTEEN="true"
FIFTEEN=false
SIXTEEN='FALSE'

# The following are not matching(incl. empty line)
17="Is not valid because the key is a number"

="Is also not valid because the key is missing"
```

Comment: Try `/(\w+)=('[^']*'|"[^"]*"|\S+)/`, see https://regex101.com/r/REoufv/1

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately there are cases where it doesn't work anymore. See [link](https://regex101.com/r/REoufv/3). I've updated my original post with another code sample

Comment: Check `([A-Za-z_]\w*)[ \t]*=[ \t]*('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^\r\n#]*)` at https://regex101.com/r/JoYiHH/1

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I couldn't check back earlier. Yes it works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
([A-Za-z_]\w*)[ \t]*=[ \t]*('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^\r\n#]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4zZZ8l/1)

- `([A-Za-z_]\w*)` - Group 1:
- `[ \t]*=[ \t]*` - a `=` enclosed with 0 or more spaces or tabs
- `('[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|[^\r\n#]*)` - Group 2:

  - `'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*'|` - a `'...'` like substring that may contain any string escape sequence, or
  - `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|` - a `"..."` like substring that may contain any string escape sequence, or
  - `[^\r\n#]*` - 0 or more chars other than `#`, CR and LF